# ASP FileUpload control issue in Chrome browser

Tags: asp.net, file, google-chrome, upload, controls

I have a legacy webpage with an `asp:FileUpload` control on it with an `OnClick` event. When uploading an .xsls spreadsheet *with* parentheses `()` in the file name, e.g., "somefile (2).xsls," using Chrome browser, the `UploadButton_Click` handler is not called. Instead, the web page redirects to the default page as if an error occurred.

However, a filename *without* parentheses works fine. (No issue with IE.)

I need help debugging this. Breakpoints in the click handler are not hitting in this scenario. `Response.Write`, etc., are not good either because the event does not get hit.

The code is pretty much this:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" runat="server">
</asp:FileUpload>

<asp:Button id="UploadButton" 
    Text="Upload file"
    OnClick="UploadButton_Click"
    runat="server">
</asp:Button>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the file name? You could probably change it in code behind before the upload.

Comment: Providing code behind example may help solving the issue. By using `PostedFile` property you can retrieve uploaded file name and save it with different one.

Comment: The page is basically blowing up on upload click so I would not be able to retrieve the name. I need a way to see how Chrome handles the file name.